# Design Finite State Machine

Tags: digital-logic, state-machines

I need to design a finite state machine that detects any invalid button sequences for a set of instructions.  The scenario is a factory where the person must press POWER, WELD, and than POWER and that is the only valid set of button sequences for the machine to work properly.  The instructions that I have state the user must press POWER to begin the machine, than WELD to weld the part, and finally POWER again to to turn off the machine.  So for example a button sequence o POWER, POWER, WELD will result in an error.  When designing the finite state machine for this scenario to capture only failures I tried to list all of the possibilities of a fail:

P P W

P P P

W W W

W P P

P W W

W W P

W P W

I think I am missing one, but I am not sure?  Now when actually designing it I have four state bubbles, with the outputs FAIL=0, FAIL=0, FAIL=0, and FAIL=1 for the last bubble. How can I go about implementing all of these cases without drawing so many lines from bubble to bubble and having a mess?  Thank you!

Comment: What do you want to happen if the user pushes POWER POWER WELD POWER?

Comment: That's an error I believe.  The instructions that I have state the user must press POWER to begin the machine, than WELD to weld the part, and finally POWER again to to turn off the machine.  So I am assuming pressing POWER twice initially will cause an error and turn off the machine.  Sorry for not stating that in my original post.

Comment: Is this a learning excercise / homework or are you designing a real machine?

Comment: It's a learning exercise/homework.

Answer (score 2):

Based on comments (the drawing tool didn't separate out the R and W; W goes to 4, and R goes to S):

[image]

Comment: Thank you! What do the asterisks * represent in the above model?  And I am assuming S is start?  So I need 6 state bubbles how many will have an output of F=0 or F=1 for a failure?

Comment: The * represents any input. States 4, 5, and 6 are all failure states.

Comment: Some of these states are redundant, no? S->P->P ends up at 6. S->W ends up at 6, etc

Comment: @dext0rb: Only if not all three presses are required. I inferred from the question that e.g. P -> P -> P would be failure all throughout and not return to the initial state after the second P.

Comment: @CharlesWitiker: If that's how you're representing the input, sure.

Comment: @CharlesWitiker: Depends. Is "PP" an invalid sequence, or are all three presses required for the sequence?

Comment: No, you need a completely different FSM in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this state transition table (notation explained in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_transition_table#Two-dimensional_state_tables)

```
            |    POWER          WELD
            | -----------------------
  ->INITIAL |        P          FAIL
          P |     FAIL            PW
         PW |      PWP          FAIL
        PWP |     FAIL          FAIL
       FAIL |     FAIL          FAIL
```

State *INITIAL* is starting state. State *PWP* is accepting state  - if you end up in this state after reading whole input sequence (must be exactly 3 button presses in defined order (power, weld, power)), you are accepting the sequence.

Otherwise if anything unwanted occurs (wrong button, incorrect number of button presses), state machine transitions to the *FAIL* state, where it stays until forever. If you end up in this state after reading whole input, you know that the user pressed incorrect buttons in incorrect order or whatever.